# Much slower response in node.js HTTP server with smaller files

Tags: node.js, performance, http

I am developing a performance test for a simple HTTP server in node.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var NO_CACHE = true;
var fileCache;
var sendFile = function(conn, file) {
    conn.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Content-Length': file.length});
    conn.write(file);
    conn.end();
}
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (NO_CACHE || fileCache == undefined) {
        fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, file) {
        fileCache = file;
        sendFile(res, fileCache);
        });
    } else {
        sendFile(res, fileCache);
    }
}).listen(8080, 'localhost');
```

(code can also be found [here](https://gist.github.com/greuze/96b73c4c641e48798d17#file-nodejs-server-js)).

The server reads always the file "index.html" and returns it. I realize that the server give the result in 1-3 ms if the file is greater than or equal to 65483 bytes (very close to 2^16 but not exact), and if the file is smaller, it last 38-40 ms to give a response (index.html file with exactly 65483 bytes can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/greuze/96b73c4c641e48798d17#file-index-html)). Headers in the response are about 128 bytes:

```
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 65483
Date: Thu, 14 May 2015 13:58:21 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

The first two headers are set by the server, and the last two are set automatically by any middleware. The file size plus the first two headers are 65533 bytes, pretty close to 65535 (2^16 - 1), the difference could be because of carriage return in those two headers.

This behaviour looks strange to me, as bigger files should last more time being read, and the difference in time is very big.

I used node.js 0.10.38 and 0.12.2 with same results. For the performance tests, I used jMeter 2.13.

For the record, this behaviour does not happen using vert.x with same file and same test plan in jMeter (with vert.x server, bigger files take more time to be read).

If anyone knows what the cause could be (and how to avoid it for small files), I am very curious to know.

Comment: can you dump the response headers for big/small files? also, if you use vert.x, you might be interested in take a look at my [bayou server](http://bayou.io)

Comment: I updated the question. There are two headers set on purpose by the server, and two other headers set automatically. The server "chunk" is pretty close to 64KB...

Comment: same response head for small file (except Content-Length)? My first instinct would be the TCP NODELAY option, which is horrible for small packets if not set. But it should be set by default for nodejs so it's probably not the reason.

Comment: Can cache cause a problem? Large files being cached, small files not being cached? (client-side or server-side)

Comment: @coyotte508 - even without any caching, it cannot be that slow (30 req/s). somebody in the middle is buffering and holding small packets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [bayou.io](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158288/bayou-io) pointed, the behaviour is caused by TCP noDelay. I added to the server:

```
server.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.setNoDelay(true);
});
```

and it is giving the response within 1-3 ms as expected.

Comment: Instead, req.socket.setNoDelay(true); can be used within the requestListener.

Comment: it is not set by default? that will burn a lot of people. that Nagle guy wasted a lot of people's time.

Comment: Node.js doc only says that noDelay defaults to true for sockets (https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setnodelay_nodelay). For HTTP request it is not told (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_setnodelay_nodelay) but my tests and other sources in the Internet confirm that it is set to false by default (the Nagle algorithm is enabled by default in HTTP requests). Nagle also wasted a lot of time in ALL my HTTP servers until now :(

Comment: I think the doc means `true` is the default value for the method parameter - `setNoDelay()` without parameter is the same as `setNoDelay(true)`. The default value for the option is still `false`

Comment: Node v16.15 has new noDelay option in createServer. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#httpcreateserveroptions-requestlistener

That option is set to true by default in Node v18.0