# node http server 4 x FASTER when keep-alive disabled?

Tags: node.js, http, server, keep-alive

Keep-alive is supposed to speed up the site.

However, when I run this dead simple server in chrome (localhost:8080), I get these loading times:

- around **100 ms** with the **"Connection: close"** header (i.e. with setHeader line uncommented)
- around **400 ms with the standard keep-alive enabled**.

What am I doing wrong ? Can anybody reproduce my result ?

I have been banging my head for the last 2 days on this.

```js
var fs = require('fs')
// preparing 50 2k files ...
var a = [], txt = '/*\n' + 'x'.repeat(2000) + '\n*/'
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var name = '/test' + i + '.js'
  fs.writeFile(__dirname + name, txt)
  a.push('<script src="' + name + '"></script>')
}
fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/index.html', a.join('\n') + '\nhello world')

var serve = function (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.statusCode = 404; return res.end()
  }
  var pth = req.url + (req.url.match(/\/$/) ? 'index.html' : '')
  var s = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + pth)
  res.on('finish', function () { console.log('done', req.url) })
  // THIS IS THE KILLER LINE. Just uncomment and restart the server.
  // on my system, the page loads 4 times FASTER
  // res.setHeader('Connection', 'close')
  res.statusCode = 200; s.pipe(res)
}
require('http').createServer(serve).listen(8080)
```

**EDIT**

for clarity, the behaviour is the same when using a **standard express server**. The following server code will yield the same results (on my system, at least)

```js
// express server code
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var closeConnection = function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Connection', 'close'); next()
}
// THIS IS THE KILLER LINE. Just uncomment and restart the server.
// on my system, the page loads 4 times FASTER
// app.use('*', closeConnection)
app.use(express.static(__dirname))
require('http').createServer(app).listen(8080)
```

Comment: Isn't that because of the lack of `Content-Length` header? I.e. the browser doesn't know when the response ends so this 400ms is kind of artificial, i.e. it includes waiting time? Unlike `Connection: close` case when the browser knows when response ends. That would be my blind shot.

Comment: No I don't think so. The behaviour is exactly the same with a standard Express server, where the issue you mention is not present. Were you able to reproduce the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be due to [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) that is [active by default](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setnodelay_nodelay). This causes a delay before sending TCP packets, waiting for possibly more data to be sent in one packet to avoid too small packets.

Because closing a connection causes the pending packet to be sent immediately, this doesn't affect latency when not using keep-alive connections.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30240641), Nagle's algorithm can be disabled like this:

```
server.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.setNoDelay(true);
});
```

This should fix the latency issue. Note that it can slow down the transfer rate if you’re not handling the buffering yourself and sending a lot of small packets.

I noticed that the problem occurs when a response is piped (causing chunked transfer-encoding to be used) (and even with a `Content-Length` header), but not when sending complete responses at once with `res.json()` for example.

Also, it seems that this issue is much less present since Node.js 8.0.0. Disabling Nagle's algorithm still has a positive effect in my case though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge difference between what's happening in your server and what is happening across the internet, although I am a little surprised at the metrics you have reported here. You didn't say how you captured the metrics nor the content generation time. We can assume the latter is under 100 mseconds, suggesting that something very weird is happening on your loopback interface, or that node.js is doing something very weird in this case, or possibly the scheduling of the browser task is blocking the webserver task.

Certainly if you are publishing pages needing more than a single file to render, and are passing data across the internet, disabling keepalives should lower your server load and CPU usage, but increase the page load times.

I would suggest you start adding in other components and see when the expected state of affairs resumes. I would start by running the client on a separate machine / running multiple clients.

Comment: Thank you for your answser. The loading times I reported simply come from the usual Chrome Developper Tools  -> network. I understand from what you say that you could not reproduce the problem, so there must be something wrong with my machine. I will try running the code on another one when I find one, and report the results. Thank you.

Comment: I've n ot tested this with node.js / chrome. I have tested it with Apache (prefork) and Firefox, ab where I found no difference in response times for a connection close / kaeepalive at the client.

Comment: Thanks @symcbeam. Chrome vs Firefox shouldn't make a difference.
I have tested access from a different device on the internal network and with Firefox, to exclude the possibility of browser & server fighting for CPU: page loading times is still about twice as much with keep-alives enabled.
I should mention that when my server is behind Nginx, the difference also goes away, because Nginx closes the connections with the backend server. May be Apache does the same ??